# BootstrapNotifier not launch activity when app not running

Tags: android, android-service, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

i have problem with [Alt Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)
I want use BootstrapNotifier. 
I need launch activity/service or create notification when application not runing. (after first launch)
I can detect beacons (Kontakt.io) when application in foreground and background. But need launch create notification when phone is near my beacons when app isn't on foreground and background.

I try download [Reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) which work for scanning beacons while application is on foreground and background but **BootstrapNotifier** not detect beacon when app was killed.

I try this reference application on android 5.1 and 8.1 but not work, still only detect beacons foreground/background.

Please how i can solve my problem? 
in reference application i change only beacon layout for Kontakt.io "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"

I was tried Eddystone and iBeacon but its the same.

Thanks for any advice

i use this version of library

```
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15'
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

my Application

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private static final String TAG = "MyApplicationName";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
    BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getApplicationContext());

    // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
    // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
    // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
    // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb.  To find the proper
    // layout expression for other beacon types, do a web search for "setBeaconLayout"
    // including the quotes.
    //
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));


    // Uncomment the code below to use a foreground service to scan for beacons. This unlocks
    // the ability to continually scan for long periods of time in the background on Andorid 8+
    // in exchange for showing an icon at the top of the screen and a always-on notification to
    // communicate to users that your app is using resources in the background.
    //
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);

    // For the above foreground scanning service to be useful, you need to disable
    // JobScheduler-based scans (used on Android 8+) and set a fast background scan
    // cycle that would otherwise be disallowed by the operating system.
    //
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

    Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
    // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            Identifier.parse("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6"), null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
    // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
    // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(getApplicationContext());
}


@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
    // Don't care
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
    // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
    // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.  
    //regionBootstrap.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
    // Don't care
}
```

///////////////
manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.par.servicebeacontest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />    <application
        android:name=".MyApplicationName"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- Note:  the singleInstance below is important to keep two copies of your activity from getting launched on automatic startup -->
        <activity
            android:name=".RangingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".test">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does your Application class implements BootstrapNotifier?

Comment: yes, i copy here

Comment: try to diable the BackgroundPowerSaver

Comment: ok, and I launch application, kill aplication and go near beacons?
I comment powerSaver launch app -> kill app and put mobile near beacons.. without action

Comment: how are you killing your app?

Comment: remove from RAM / clear RAM

Comment: You must be out of region when you will kill the app for it to get a didEnter callback.  Have you ensured it is out of region, if so, how?

Comment: ok i try kill ap when im out of region.after it going near beacons

Comment: not any effect.